# Magento: set "container1" to all existing products

Tags: magento

I need to set Display Options to "Product info column" (container1) for all my products (7000+).
I execute this script but any modifications are done to my products.
I'm on magento 1.9.0.1...where is the problem?
Otherwise, is more simple done a DB query?

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($products as $product){
        $prod=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->setOptionsContainer('container1')->save();
        echo "SKU [". $product->getSku() ."] set ". $prod->getAttributeText('options_container') ."<br>";
        usleep(50000);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run sql query to find out attribute id in table

```
eav_attribute
```

find with code like `options_container`

for my it is 109

you can run sql

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 109 AND (`store_id` = 1 OR `store_id` = 4)
```

you can replace your store_id as well if you have multiple store you can adjust or set **0** for default store

**Update Query**

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar set value = 'container1' where attribute_id = 109
```

hope this will sure help you to quick update.